# Sriarcha, Shampoo and Unexpected Trajectories

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Some time last year my parents-in-law related to me a story which rang true in my scientific brain.

They had gone out to see a show, and then decided to go to a fancy Asian restaurant. One course came through that required my father-in-law to reach for the sriarcha chili sauce and dispense some into a small bowl. The bottle was similar to one of those squeezy types just like the ketchup and mustard ones at the hot dog stands (squeeze, condiment gets dispensed through nozzle).

This is where things get interesting (and a little messy). My father-in-law claims he dispensed the sriarcha in a downward fashion onto the sloped side inside the bowl, which then started off forming a little pool, but then, unexpectedly came out in a small jet of sauce, landing on my mother-in-law's top (Needless to say she wasn't impressed).

Now, when I heard this I knew I had seen this phenomenon before. I've seen it when dispensing shampoo onto a sloped hand and seen it form a little pool of the fluid and then leap out in an completely different direction... Before continuing to collect and then do it again, and so on... I've seen this happen generally with fairly viscous fluids like shampoo, ketchup, American mustard, certain types of honey, and now I can add sriarcha to the list...

What is this phenomenon called and why does it happen?

Bonus points if you know how to get sriarcha out of a white blouse...

Comment: Some quick searching resulted in [the Kaye effect](https://youtu.be/vregrv8lIcQ) and [the Kaye effect](http://www.nature.com/news/2006/060403/full/news060403-10.html).

Comment: A diagram or something would help.

Comment: @DanielSank is that to me or to @march?

Comment: I don't know who @march is.

Comment: @DanielSank I think March got the answer... it *is* the Kaye effect... That's what I've seen and was talked about by my father-in-law...